# Is there a way for selenium to click the like button (without using class)? (refer to picture)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

tried a couple of methods with selenium, didn't work for me.

1. `bot.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-testid="like"]').click()`
2. `bot.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label = 'Like']/*[name()='svg']").click()`
3. `bot.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@role = 'button']").click()`

[ss of the inspect segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxagR.png)

//edit//
my attempt to click the like button in this tweet!

https://twitter.com/RichardEudes/status/1196798030529335296

my code is as follows

```
# link is the url above
for link in stored_links:
                bot.get(link)
                bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Like']/div/div").click()
                time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `WebDriverWait` to your code sample as well:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# link is the url above
for link in stored_links:
    bot.get(link)
    like_button = WebDriverWait(bot, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Like']/div/div")))

    like_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I used the above code to successfully click the Like button on the tweet provided.

**Breaking down this code sample:**

`from` statements at the top -- these are used to include all of the Selenium libraries we need. `By` is used for locators, specifically `By.XPATH` here. `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` are both used for the explicit wait, where we wait for the like button to be visible before clicking it.

`WebDriverWait(bot, 10)` declares a new instance of an explicit wait, specifically with a timeout of 10 seconds -- meaning, this method fails if the condition is not met within 10 seconds.

`EC.presence_of_element_located` is the condition we are waiting on -- in this case, we are waiting on the presence of a certain element. `By.XPATH, "//div...div"` specifies which element we are waiting on.

The line `like_button = WebDriverWait(bot, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Like']/div/div")))` is waiting on the presence of the element located through `//div[@aria-label='Like']/div/div`. If the element is not found within 10 seconds, a `TimeoutException` will be thrown.

Lastly, `WebDriverWait` returns the WebElement which is found after waiting -- so, `like_button` is the WebElement object we were waiting to exist. That is how we are able to click the button through `like_button.click()`, because we are using the reference to the WebElement we stored in the previous `WebDriverWait` step.

Comment: it doesn't seem to click the like button still though, although i don't think there are multiple elements with ```aria-label='Like'```

Comment: That would definitely cause an issue.  The XPath I provided is valid for the HTML you posted, but without context of the entire page it's hard to tell what is going wrong. If you know the index of the Like button you want to click, you can try `//div[@aria-label='Like'][1]/div/div/svg`, replacing `1` with the index of the button you wish to click. If you want a more complete answer, it would be best to post a link to the page you are automating, or the full HTML (text, not a  screenshot) of the page.

Comment: I have added the details above in what I am trying to click! Perhaps that will help solve the problem!

Comment: That helps quite a bit -- I just took a look at the page, and I don't think you need to click the `svg` at all. I've shortened the path a bit, and tested against the page you provided, where it seems to be working.

Comment: I tried both methods, doesn't seem to work for me though... tweet still doesn't get liked (edit: one moment, im facing a different error)

Comment: Figured it might be my try and except that was hindering this, received this error
/
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@aria-label='Like']/div/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Comment: So I just wrote up a script to navigate to the page with a bot and click the Like button. Turns out, Twitter changes the HTML on the page based on whether or not you are logged in. After a few attempts, I was able to click the Like button (while logged out) using the above code. Currently trying to figure out the case where user is logged in already.

Comment: ah I see, very interesting. Do let me know if this can be figured out. Also, I have attached my particular code snippet above, if that is of any help!

Comment: I just tested your code sample in my Python IDE and successfully clicked the like button.

Comment: It raised another error for the clicking part. (following your latest code)

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-xoduu5">...</div> is not clickable at point (464, 11). Other element would receive the click: <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2 r-1pi2tsx r-1777fci">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Comment: Ok, I managed to resolve everything. Here are the full instructions.

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

- edited `driver` to `bot`
- removed the scrolling to the bottom worked for me

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, got a bit mixed up when moving code from my IDE into this post. Updated with the changes you mentioned.

Comment: May i just ask for a quick explanation of what you did? and the rationale? Haha, learning process

Comment: Just added additional explanation & breakdown of what was changed -- hope this helps!